# Cycles black band on render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am rendering a single image using cycles and I have black rectangle.  I have used instancing to create the concrete sides and pillars across the top, and the original collection renders perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'The Object' ?

Comment: The concrete sides and pillars across the top.

Comment: Check the outliner for hidden placeholder objects that may be overlapping with the wall.

Comment: definitely overlapping objects or faces.

Comment: Thank you yes it's overlapping objects, so much to learn!!